# Simple UIContextMenuConfiguration causes Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, ios13

I created a simple ContextMenu

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil){ action in
            let delete = UIAction(title: "Delete", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash.fill"), identifier: nil,discoverabilityTitle: nil, attributes: .destructive, handler: {action in
                self.deleteItem(index: indexPath.item)
            })
            
            return UIMenu(title: "", image: nil, identifier: nil, children: [delete])
        }
        
        return configuration
    }
```

and it causes the following warning in the console.

```
2020-07-16 22:58:16.227394+0200 RunPersonalRecord[8410:2186970] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x280eec230 h=--& v=--& UIInterfaceActionGroupView:0x1658ca700.height == 0   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280ed7e80 groupView.actionsSequence....height >= 44   (active, names: groupView.actionsSequence...:0x158340200 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280ed4a00 UIInterfaceActionGroupView:0x1658ca700.top == _UIContentConstraintsLayoutGuide:0x157d4dae0''.top   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280ed4140 V:[_UIContentConstraintsLayoutGuide:0x157d4dae0'']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIInterfaceActionGroupView:0x1658ca700 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280ed6710 groupView.actionsSequence....top == _UIContentConstraintsLayoutGuide:0x157d4dae0''.top   (active, names: groupView.actionsSequence...:0x158340200 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280ed6760 groupView.actionsSequence....bottom == _UIContentConstraintsLayoutGuide:0x157d4dae0''.bottom   (active, names: groupView.actionsSequence...:0x158340200 )>") Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint <NSLayoutConstraint:0x280ed7e80 groupView.actionsSequence....height >= 44   (active, names: groupView.actionsSequence...:0x158340200 )>
```

Could it be an apple bug or it is possible to fix somehow? Thanks!

Comment: can you share the part of the code where you are attaching `UIMenu` to the main view?

Comment: It is very unlikely to this code be your issue. Check your `groupView` constraints

Comment: i create the ContextMenu inside of contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt

Comment: found 2 project on GitHub with same functionality and both cause the problem i described. Looks like an apple bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to apple forum it is a system bug. For now we should just ignore these warnings. Has no effect on the end user.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/654647?page=1#621883022